# Follow chat room feature (for everyone or just ROs, depending on which is better)

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, room-owner

Can we have an option to follow a chat room? This may seem like overkill if you are only familiar with highly active chat rooms, but there have been times where I (or another user replying to my comments) created a chat from the prompt:

> **Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to [automatically move this discussion to chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375470/follow-chat-room-feature-for-everyone-or-just-ros-depending-on-which-is-better#)**

and had discussions with multiple users regarding a post. Usually, after the discussion, the chat room gets forgotten and we all move on. But sometimes, I would look back at it, and see that more messages that I would've liked to address at the time of the discussion, got posted.

This feature may also come in handy if you are the RO *(room owner)* of a chat room of little to no activity, so if it's not a good idea for regular users to follow any chat room, can the RO of a room have the option?

Note that **when we follow a post** with a discussion going on in the comments, **our notifications get cut off** once the *""Let us continue this discussion in chat"* message appears and the commenters continue in the chat room.

Comment: Hm... what, exactly, would "following" a room imply, can you expand on that in the question? As it stated, it is not clear what benefits it would have over simply adding a room to the list of "favorite" rooms and checking in from time to time.

Comment: Getting notifications for the chat messages, just like how we get notifications for the comments when following a post.